# Changing font on Ubuntu 14.04 using unity-tweak-tool causes session to logout

Tags: 14.04, fonts, unity-tweak-tool

I've downloaded the `Roboto` font using `typecatcher`. I've installed `unity-tweak-tool` and when I change the default font (or only its size) my session is logged out.

I'm using 14.04 LTS in a Dell Inspiron 5000 (i15-5548).

Someone has passed by the same?